# How to check if an object is convertible to another type?

Tags: java, type-conversion

Let's say I have two string objects: "25000.00", and "1234" that my program gets at run time. How do I check if they are <strike>castable</strike> convertible to type double and int, respectively? Is there a method or keyword in Java that does that already?

Comment: To learn about casting, check this tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40402756/547270

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `Integer.parseInt` or `Double.parseDouble` static methods to do this.  Each of these methods takes in a `String` and converts them to an `int` or `double` as appropriate.  You can check whether the string is convertible by calling this function.  If the conversion is possible, it will be performed.  Otherwise, the methods will throw `NumberFormatException`s, which you can catch and respond to.  For example:

```
try {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(myString);
    // Yes!  An integer.
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // Not an integer
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify: `String` is **never** castable to `Double` or `Integer`.

However, you can *parse* a String as a number using the `Double.parseDouble` and `Integer.parseInt` methods. If they are not parsable then a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown. You can catch that and handle it appropriately.

*Casting* and *parsing* are quite different things.

EDIT: I see @BalusC has edited the question and changed "cast" to "convert". I guess my comments are redundant now :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I always thought casting and parsing are the same thing.

Comment: Definitely not. Both are however forms of conversion.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, there is a method to check whether an object is can be cast to other object. But I guess, Integer.parseInt or Double.parseDouble suffice.