# Check if a string is parsable as another Java type

Tags: java, class, parsing, casting

I'm trying to find a way to check if a string is parsable as a specific type.

My use case is :

- I've got a dynamic html form created from a map of field (name and type)
- In my controller I get back the form values from the http request as strings
- I'd like to check if the retrieved string is parsable as the wanted type, in order to display an error message in the form if this is not possible.

Does someone know a way to check if the parsing is possible without testing each type one by one ? (Double, Integer, Date, BigDecimal, etc.)

I'm looking for something like that in Java or in a third party library :

```
myString.isParsableAs(Class<?> wantedType)
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: How should this work? `"2".isParsableAs(Integer.class)` would be `true` just like `"2".isParsableAs(Double.class)` would be `true` just like `"2".isParsableAs(BigDecimal.class)` would be `true` and so on...

Comment: Yes this is the idea, and "abc".isParsableAs(Double.class) would be false

Comment: But which of the three cases I mentioned would be your "correct" case and why?

Comment: Would "abc".isParsableAs(Double.class) not mean that you need to extend String, what seems impossible?

Comment: All of these use case are correct, I have a string, and I have a type I expect, just want to know if the value of the string could be parsed as the expected type.

Comment: Yes I know isParsableAs isn't implemented in the String class, and I won't extend it don't worry ;) Just want to know if this check can be done simply with some methods I wouldn't know about...

Answer (score 2):

Make a map from `Class` to `Predicate`, and use that to obtain a "tester object" for your class. Here is an example:

```
static Map<Class<?>,Predicate<String>> canParse = new HashMap<>();
static {
    canParse.put(Integer.TYPE, s -> {try {Integer.parseInt(s); return true;} catch(Exception e) {return false;}});
    canParse.put(Long.TYPE, s -> {try {Long.parseLong(s); return true;} catch(Exception e) {return false;}});
};
```

You can now retrieve a predicate for the class, and test your string, like this:

```
if (canParse.get(Long.TYPE).test("1234567890123")) {
    System.out.println("Can parse 1234567890123");
} else {
    System.out.println("Cannot parse 1234567890123");
}
```

You wouldn't have to go though the entire list of testers; the check will happen only for the type that you want to test.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/9TIFND)

Comment: "Does someone know a way to check if the parsing is possible without testing each type one by one ?" ;-)

Comment: @Smutje Could you please make your point, rather than writing a smiley and assuming that everyone would guess exactly what you mean?

Comment: Why do you assume that "You wouldn't have to go though the entire list of testers; the check will happen only for the type that you want to test" - if (canParse.get(Long.TYPE).test("2")) would be equally true like if (canParse.get(Integer.TYPE).test("2")) or not?

Comment: @Smutje OP already has a type - that's the `wantedType` in his `myString.isParsableAs(Class<?> wantedType)` call. He turns that into `canParse.get(wantedType).test(myString)`, and he's done. No loops, just one check.

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, it's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I just wanted to know if it exists a more generic solution, to avoid having to implement the test for each type because the list would be long and not exhaustive.

Comment: @Arthur There is no built-in solution for this in the Java library. Heck, they don't even offer a method to test if a string can be parsed or not without having to catch an exception.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's too bad, thanks anyway, I'll go with your solution with the most common used types for now...